# What XML parser should I use with Delphi XE2 for iOS projects?

Tags: ios, xml, windows, delphi, parsing

I can't find compatible parser which can be used on Windows in Delphi XE2 and after exporting Firemonkey iOS App to Xcode on Mac OS. What parser is compatible with iOS?

Comment: +1 Looking forward for good answers on this, as XML support for iOS is definitely lacking in Delphi XE2 right now.

Comment: iOS support is lacking in Delphi. There is no and most probably never will be iOS in Delphi. Period. There is iOS support in FreePascal (for Delphi XE2) and there is iOS support for "Mobile Studio" (Rumored future part of XE3). There is no suc hthing as iOs support in Delphi. Search for FreePascal XML parsers, that is correct technical term. Pity that  topicstarter already filled all five tag slots, freepascal tag would make more sense and would show the question to the target community.

Comment: @Arioch, Can FreePascal parser has some Win dependencies? In this case if I find FPC parser for Delphi it can't be compatible with iOS, could it be? Or I'm not right?

Comment: It can have or it can have not. Pure Pascal would not have. Wrapper around MSXML or Xerces - liek that TXMLDocument - would have.

Comment: May i ask you for the 3rd time - did you try Jedi CodeLib parser ?

Comment: Not yet, but I will. I still try to do smth with NativeXML

Answer (score 3):

I believe that [NativeXML](http://www.simdesign.nl/nativexml.html) is compatible with Windows, Mac and iOS.

Comment: Trying it. I have many errors... Compiler can't find CodecUtilsWin32 and EncodingUtils, I found that now this files are dkCodecUtilsWin32 and dkEncodingUtils. After I add them it says "not enough parameters in function `sdWideToUtf8Buffer(lpWideCharStr^, lpMultiByteStr^, cchWideChar)`. This function doesn't have boolean parameter and I just add it. After this project can be compiled on Windows. After exporting to Xcode Mac OS compiler says "Can't find unit Windows used by dkCodecUtilsWin32". This unit is located in this block:`{$IFNDEF LINUX}
uses
  { Delphi }
  Windows;
{$ENDIF}`

Comment: After commenting this block compiler says about other errors but strange that all these errors are located in `{$IFNDEF LINUX}////{$ENDIF}`

Comment: @KDV well, they probably do not have FreeBSD tag in FreePascal :-)
What is iOS if not mix of Mach kernel, FreeBSD middleware and Apple graphics ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan With pleasure. But access to the forum I can get only after purchasing NativeXML, its a problem right now, but may be in future I will purchase.

Comment: Sure you can get onto the forum. See here: http://www.simdesign.nl/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2121  That purports to solve the exact question that you ask

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I saw this and try it but without good result.  May be I don't understand smth because I don't know English well. Well, I will try more)

Comment: @ShaunRoselt It used to. But 4 years have passed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you maybe edit the link and provide a new one if you know of any?

Comment: @Shaun I could look around. But so could you. Feel free to edit this answer. That's how the site works.

Comment: @ShaunRoselt Thank you.

Comment: If remember correctly, the code is now on sourceforge (all SimDesign code is)

Answer (score 1):

Jedi CodeLibrary has built-in XML engine. They also generalyl have FreePascal as their target.

One more reportedly pure-pascal implementation: http://gurin.tomsknet.ru/delphixml.html , download link at page bottom

Generally, you'd better go FreePascal forums and ask there for Delphi-compatible XML library.

Comment: As it was with NativeXML, OmniXML wasn't tested on iOS and developer don't know about compatability. It needs testing, who can help?)

Comment: 1) Did You checked JCL ? That was the main point of my answer and you seems to miss sidestep it! ///
2) Forget about "iOS" word. There is no iOS in Delphi and never be. For XE2 iOS means "FreePascal". For XE3 iOS would probably mean "Mobile Studio" if that black box would ever be open. There is no and now is almost settled there never will be iOS in Delphi. So search for "FreePascal XML parsers with Delphi support", not "Delphi iOS XML parser" which is oxymoron.  ///
3) you can try forum http://dir.gmane.org/search.php?match=pascal

Comment: Of course I understand that it's fpc, just call it like that. Thanks